# How could I implement x,y coordinates of a pixel color?

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c

How can I implement X,Y coordinates of a piksel color with Objective C or C#? For example; at x:20,y:30 coordinates, rgb values are 255,255,255.

Thanks...

Comment: I must admit... I have **no** clue what you are asking here!

Comment: Are you talking about implementing a color picker functionality?  Or just visualizing a slice out of the 3d color space?

Answer (score 1):

Getting the color of a bitmap picture is part of the [.net framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx). You can then use the Color.A, R, G values. To perform a screencapture you can simply call the Graphics.CopyFromScreen method.

We'll need more info if that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: That is probably what he is asking. Good call :)

Answer (score 0):

I think space's example means: Given x and y screen coordinates of an iPhone display, what colour is the pixel that is currently showing there?

If that is the case, there is sample code here:
http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/